# How to overcome missing INSERT statements in MySQL dump?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table backup. A really big one.
But when I restoring it by

```
mysql -u example -p example < backup.sql
```

I have an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

I have looked into this file and noticed that there are no INSERT instructions - just values like

```
(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3);
(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)
```

Therefore I have two questions:

- Why did it happen?
- How to restore from this file? I have no ability to make a new one.

Comment: More info from this `backup.sql` file is needed.

Comment: You can probably just edit the `backup.sql`, add ```INSERT INTO `database_name`.`table_name` VALUES```  in the beginning then save. Try to import again after that. How did you dump the file? Any tool or code that you use?

Comment: By the way, I see a semi-colon there so that means you have to append the `INSERT INTO` syntax after every semi-colon.. assuming that all the data inside `backup.sql` are consistently like what you've posted.

Comment: Yeah that migt help but I ask for different solution if it exists. Because backup is over 40GB and it is hard a bit to append INSERTs everywhere.

Comment: What about tool - I don't know which tool was used. This is not my file. I just want to restore it.

Comment: You have a file but no idea where the data is to go to? I don't see how we can help.

Comment: You could do a replace `;` with `; insert into table (cols...) Values ` with a replace all but you need to know that they're all for the same table

Comment: Well, you can ask whoever file that is to re-dump properly then. If that 40GB sql backup is only for a single table and you still want to work with that file, there's no choice other than appending `INSERT INTO ...` in it (that I know of). Otherwise, if the dump file is a full database or from multiple tables then that file is useless. How can you know which data goes into which table?

Comment: Ok guys. Thanks. I've just asked for a different way if it exists. I've replaced all `;` already. But it have taken a time.